# Find number of elements in a set given the number of subsets it has

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

How do I find the number of elements in a set that has exactly $16$ subsets and an odd number of elements?

I don't really understand.

I mean I know that the number of subsets in a set is equal to $2^n$, where $n$ is the number of elements in the set. So here if the number of subsets is $16$, I would say that the set has $4$ elements ($2^4 = 16$). But it says that the set has an odd number of elements.. and $4$ is not odd. In the book, the answer is $5$, and I don't understand how that would be.

Comment: but with the 2^n formula you count that too.. right. for example the set {1, 2} it has 0, 1, 2, 12.

Comment: 2^2 so 2 elements

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Can you quote the exact formulation of the question from the book?

Comment: Find the number of elements of a set that has exactly 16 subsets with an odd number of elements

Comment: It's the *subsets* that have an odd number of elements, not the original set.

Comment: ooh. I get it. thanks. so we only take the subsets with and odd number of elements. so that would be  2^{n-1}  = 16 so n = 5